# Runtime Error: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'leaflet'

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have problem with leaflet dictionary. I saw similar problems on stackoverflow, but it has not been resolved. I reinstalled leaflet and types, but there is still a problem. When I import L from leaflet, i have this problem

I installed leaflet like that `npm install leaflet` and `npm install @types/leaflet`

This is line of code where i have problem

`import * as L from 'leaflet'`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the exact error you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `import L from 'leaflet'` :)

Comment: I used that earlier```Module '"xyz/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index"' has no default export.ts(1192)```

Comment: Can you try :
`import 'leaflet';  const L = window['L'];`

Comment: If this doesn't work put `allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true` in your typescript config file.

Comment: I must use global and source, now import leaflet in typings.json and package.json. I have a problem with old source type. ```error TS1110: Type expected.```